# How to create a function to count occurrences of each letter?

Tags: c

In C, I need to create a function that, for an input, will count and display the number of times each letter occurs.

For input of "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", the function should return something similar to:

```
a: 0
b: 0
c: 0
d: 1
e: 2
f: 0
...
```

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: If it only needs to work for ASCII, you need 128 counts.

Comment: It does say every *letter*, not every *character*.  So, you only need 26 or 52, depending on case-sensitivity.

Comment: @dan, true, depending on how exactly the assignment's phrased.

Comment: It only applies to letters, and it will ignore the case, so I figure that it will need 26 cases (with the use of && for the lower and upper case letters in each).

Comment: @Gabe: ["the homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812)

Comment: @not_l33t: What have you tried so far?  What part of the problem is giving you difficulty?  How have you broken it down into subproblems?  http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Roger: Sure enough, it looks like the guidelines have changed since I last checked. Obviously, I agree with the former guidelines.

Comment: @Gabe: You have to use an @ to [reply](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019).

Comment: Roger: I don't have an @ key.

Comment: -1 .This is not a question,Show your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you will basically need to read through the entire file char-by-char. Assuming that you know how file-reading works, you will need to do something like (apologies, been a while since I did C):

```
if (isalpha(ch)) {
  count[ch-'a']++;
}
/* rest of code where char pointer is moved on etc. */
```

You will need to import the ctype library for that:

```
#include <ctype.h>
```

** forgot to mention, assumed you would deduce the following: ch is your pointer to the currently read in character, while count[] is an int[], initialized to all zeros with a size of (26 * 2) = 52 to cater for both upper and lowercase. If upper and lower-case should be treated the same, you can use the tolower(int c) function also included in the ctype library. In this case you only need a 26 size array.

```
if (isalpha(ch)) {
  count[tolower(ch)-'a']++;
}
```

Then the count[] should contain the counts for each character.

/* *********** */

If you wanted to do this with only the stdio.h library, you can implement the two functions used from the ctype.h library.

A simple implementation of the isalpha(int c) function could be something like:

```
if (((int)c >= 'a' && (int)c <= 'z') || ((int)c >= 'A' && (int)c <= 'Z') {
  return TRUE;
} else {
  return FALSE;
}
```

(where TRUE and FALSE are of type your return type and something you defined).

And a REALLY simple version of tolower could be something like:

```
if ((int)c >= 'A' && (int)c <= 'Z') {
  return (int)c - 'a';
} else {
  return (int)c;
}
```

You could probably do without all the casts...

Comment: Would it be possible to use the stdio library for a similar code? I am far more familiar with it.

Comment: Yes, but you will have to write your own implementations for the isalpha and tolower functions. This in it's own should not be too bad. I will show a prototype in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

hints:

```
char c[26] = { 0 }; // init
// read each input chars
    ++c[input-'a'];
```

Comment: will break as soon as you hit any non-alpha char

Comment: Presumably, that's covered in the omitted `if` statement within the omitted `for` statement.

Comment: @Matthew just trying to give enough, not all solution

Answer (score 1):

I would have an array (of the size equal to char domain) and increment the count at  apropriate position.

```
 count[ch]++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are concerned with speed:

unsigned int chars[255], *p = text;

while(*p)
   chars[*p]++;

for(int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
   if(i > ('A' - 1) && i < ('Z' + 1))
      printf("%c) %u/n", i, chars[i];

Sorry for the "/n" but my mac pro does not have the right character on its keyboard...